# Crystal Reports 2008 Customize underline

Tags: crystal-reports, formatting

I want to import a text from HTML file in Crystal Reports 2008 for our software. 
And I tried to make a formula for underline in Crystal to underline my text with dots no matter if the cell in HTML is empty or not. I mention that I search for 4 or 5 hours but nothing useful. Thanks for advice.

For example, i want to use dots to underline the formula for "{denumire_societate}"

[image]

Comment: not understand that "use dots to underline the formula"? you are shows {denumire_societate} is field, which replace html code? right and you want this text to be underline, right?. then your formula editor work. explained where you stuck.

Comment: He wants his underline not to be a solid line but with dots.

Comment: I want to underline a specific word/formula from a text located in a text box, like {denumire_societate} without put the word in a separate text box, and edit lower border to pun underline with dots. I mentionated about HTML cause i found a post that says i can put a HTML code to get underline with dots. In the picture i check the "underline" and then i press "x2" for formula. Hope you understand me. Thanks.

Comment: Formulas allows you to apply the underline but doesn't change how the underline looks. Why is formatting bottom border not an acceptable answer?

Comment: Because it force me to make a format that won't change if the formulas bring less or more characters. I need to find a way, because i need to recreate an official document.

Comment: What about CSS to use dotted underline? www.csstothepoint.com/dottedunderline.htm

Comment: I can use that in Crystal? Where?

Comment: Inline CSS using style tag?

Answer (score 0):

- Right click on your field and select Format Field
- Border tab
- Change Bottom -> Dotted
- You can optionally create a formula if you want to present Dotted Underline with specific conditions

[image: Format Border Bottom Dotted]

Comment: Thanks, but it's not the answer that i'm looking.

Comment: Do you have a better answer or another answer at all?

Comment: I know the trick with the lower border, but i need something else, i post upper more info. The simple idea is to underline something without using the border from text box.

Comment: I work in a small company that sells a ERP software, and we got a client that needs to complete a formular in the software which is created in HTML and then, the information need to be imported in Crystal Reports, nothing too complicated by now. Now comes the problem, the client wants a specific number of dots for underline, but i told her i can't do that, but i will try to underline with dots the information. So i try to put every formula in a text box but the result is not so great because if she complete "potato potato ching chang tomato" in {denumire_societate} and my field is only 10 char

Comment: Then the design will be very bad at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I want another answer because i want to underline only some words, and i don't wanna put them in separate text box because it will looks unesthetical.
In the picture, i got a text box with many words, formulas, etc, i want to underline a specific one like: {denumire_societate}, {adresa}, {nr_reg_com}, {cui}, {cont}, and the underline to be form by dots.

[Text box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utbbr.jpg)